# Possible to use type_traits / SFINAE to find if a class defines a member TYPE?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence) which allows one to check for the existence of a **member function**, but I'm trying to find out whether a class has a **member type**.

In the example below, both evaluate to "false", but I would like to find a way so that `has_bar<foo1>::value` evaluates to false, and `has_bar<foo2>::value` evaluates to **true**.

Is this possible?

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo1;
struct foo2 { typedef int bar; };

template <typename T>
class has_bar
{
    typedef char yes;
    typedef long no;

    template <typename C> static yes check( decltype(&C::bar) ) ;
    template <typename C> static no  check(...);
public:
    enum { value = sizeof(check<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes) };
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << has_bar<foo1>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_bar<foo2>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit: implementing a specialisation in response to the answers below:**

> ...if you use C::bar in the target template, the template will be
>   discarded automatically for types that don't have that nested type.

I have tried to do this, but am clearly missing something

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo1;
struct foo2 { typedef int bar; };

template <typename T, typename U = void>
struct target
{
    target()
    {
        std::cout << "default target" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct target<T, typename T::bar>
{
    target()
    {
        std::cout << "specialized target" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    target<foo1>();
    target<foo2>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `foo1` is incomplete – is this intentional?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot obtain a pointer to member to a type member:

```
template <typename C> static yes check( decltype(&C::bar) ) ;
```

The subexpression `&C::bar` will only be valid when `bar` is a non-type member of `C`. But what you need to check is whether it is a *type*. A minimal change to your template could be:

```
template <typename C> static yes check( typename C::bar* ) ;
```

If `bar` is a nested type of `C`, then that function overload will be a valid candidate (the 0 will be a pointer to whatever `C::bar` type is), but if `C` does not contain a nested `bar` then it will be discarded and the second test will be the only candidate.

There is a different question as of whether the trait is needed at all, since if you use `C::bar` in the target template, the template will be discarded automatically for types that don't have that nested type.

---

*EDIT*

What I meant is that in your approach you need to create a trait for each and every possible nested type, just to generate a template that does or does not hold a nested type (`enable_if`). Let's take a different approach... First we define a general utility to select a type based on a condition, this is not *required* for this problem, and a simpler `template <typename T> void_type { typedef void type; };` would suffice, but the utility template can be useful in other cases:

```
// General utility: if_<Condition, Then, Else>::type
// Selects 'Then' or 'Else' type based on the value of 
// the 'Condition'
template <bool Condition, typename Then, typename Else = void>
struct if_ {
   typedef Then type;
};
template <typename Then, typename Else>
struct if_<false, Then, Else > {
   typedef Else type;
};
```

Now se just need to use SFINAE for class template specializations:

```
template <typename T, typename _ = void> 
struct target {
   // generic implementation
};

template <typename T>
struct target<T, typename if_<false,typename T::bar>::type> {
   // specialization for types holding a nested type `T::bar`
};
```

Note that the main difference with your approach is the use of an extra intermediate template (the one for which Substitution will Fail --and Is Not An Error) that yields a `void` type (on success). This is the reason why the `void_type` template above would also work: you just need to use the nested type as argument to a template, and have that fail, you don't really care what the template does, as long as the evaluation is a nested `type` (that must be `void`) if it succeeds.

In case it is not obvious (it wasn't at first for me) why your approach doesn't work, consider what the compiler needs to do when it encounters `target<foo2>`: The first step is finding that there is a template called `target`, but that template takes two arguments of which only one was provided. It then looks in the *base template* (the one that is not specialized) and finds that the second argument can be defaulted to `void`. From this point on, it will consider your instantiation to be: `target<foo2,void>` (after injecting the defaulted argument). And it will try to match the best specialization. Only specializations for which the second argument *is* `void` will be considered. Your template above will only be able to use the specialized version if `T::bar` is `void` (you can test that by changing `foo2` to: `struct foo2 { typedef void bar; }`. Because you don't want the specialization to kick in *only* when the nested type is `void` you need the extra template that will take `C::bar` (and thus fail if the type does not contain a nested `bar`) but will *always* yield `void` as the nested type.

Comment: Thanks David. I have been able to get the trait to return what I wanted, but then tried to implement this without using a trait at all, as you suggested. I have edited my question to reflect this - would you be able to comment on how to achieve what you were suggesting?

Comment: @lori : David is not suggesting that a trait is _never_ needed, only that it might not be needed in your particular use-case -- in many cases, a trait is exactly the appropriate solution, but in others it might be overkill. For example, see [this demo](http://ideone.com/6gxtW) which does not use a trait, but uses simple overloading instead. If you _do_ need a trait, [this demo](http://ideone.com/dhK9A) shows one.

Comment: This will not work for types that are hidden by non-types, such as `struct A { void bar(); struct bar {}; };`

Comment: @Johannes : OTOH, I'd be okay with shooting anyone who writes code like that, so \*shrug\*. :-P

Comment: @lori: I have updated the answer to show how you don't really need to write a handcrafted trait class to detect this, and a generic approach will be both more concise and flexible.

Comment: With C++11, there's no need to define `if_`, you can use `std::conditional`

Answer (score 15):

Try this

```
template<class T>
struct Void {
  typedef void type;
};

template<class T, class U = void>
struct has_bar {
    enum { value = 0 };
};

template<class T>
struct has_bar<T, typename Void<typename T::bar>::type > {
    enum { value = 1 };
};
```

Comment: +1, This is probably the simplest approach to get the trait (although I would avoid writing a trait for that, as the same technique can be directly applied where needed)

Comment: this is coming to the standard under the name `void_t`

Comment: I prefer `struct has_bar final: public std::(false|true)_type`, as then you get its typedefs, converting constructors, etc. for free.

Answer (score 2):

C++20 Update:

It is now much more easier to check whether a given type contains a specific type definition.

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept has_bar = requires {
    typename  T::bar;
};
```

... so your example code evolves to this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct foo1;
struct foo2 { typedef int bar; };

template <typename T, typename U = void>
struct target
{
    target()
    {
        std::cout << "default target" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
requires(has_bar<T>)
struct target<T>
{
    target()
    {
        std::cout << "specialized target" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    target<foo1>();
    target<foo2>();
    return 0;
}
```

Example on gcc.godbolt: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/a15G13

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to wrap it in macro.

test.h:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename ...>
struct void_type
{
     using type = void;
};

template<typename ...T>
using void_t = typename void_type<T...>::type;

#define HAS_TYPE(NAME) \
template<typename, typename = void> \
struct has_type_##NAME: std::false_type \
{}; \
template<typename T> \
struct has_type_##NAME<T, void_t<typename T::NAME>>: std::true_type \
{} \

HAS_TYPE(bar);
```

test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo1;
struct foo2 { typedef int bar; };

int main()
{
    std::cout << has_type_bar<foo1>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_type_bar<foo2>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```